# How avoid multiple data insert on double clicking button

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I have done data insert using ajax call. when click submit button,it wil redirect to view page.but the problem is that.when continuously clicking on submit button,multiple entries gone to database.how prevent this. i give my code below.please help.

Controller

```
 public function addmerchant() {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->helper('file');

         $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
         $config['upload_path'] = 'assets/images/merchantquote';
        $config['allowed_types'] ='gif|jpg|jpeg|png|pdf|doc|docx|txt';
        $config['max_size'] = '1000';
        $config['max_width'] = '2024';
        $config['max_height'] = '1768';
        $config['width'] = 75;
        $config['height'] = 50;
         if (isset($_FILES['txtattachments']['name'])) {
            $filename = "-" . $_FILES['txtattachments']['name'];
            $config['file_name'] = substr(md5(time()), 0, 28) . $filename;
        }
        $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
        $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
        $field_name = "txtattachments";
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
         if (!$this->upload->do_upload('txtattachments')) {
                //no file uploaded or failed upload
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            } else {
                $dat6 = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                $this->resize($dat6['upload_data']['full_path'], $dat6['upload_data']['file_name']);
            }
            if (empty($dat6['upload_data']['file_name'])) {
                $merimage = '';
            } else {
                $merimage = $dat6['upload_data']['file_name'];
            }
        $data7 = array(
            'qub_merchantid' => $this->input->post('merchant'),
            'qub_customerid' => $this->input->post('customer'),
            'qub_shipcontactname' => $this->input->post('txtShipContactName'),
            'qub_shipaddress' => $this->input->post('txtAddress'),  
            'qub_shiplocation'=>$this->input->post('txtLocation'),  
            'qub_telephone'=>$this->input->post('txtTelephone'), 
            'qub_mobile'=>$this->input->post('txtMobile'), 
            'qub_email'=>$this->input->post('txtEmail'), 
            'qub_payterms'=>$this->input->post('txtPayterms'),
            'qub_paymode'=>$this->input->post('txtPaymode'),
            'qub_deliveryperiod'=>$this->input->post('txtDelivery'),
            'qub_incoterms'=>$this->input->post('txtIncoterms'),
            'qub_attachment'=>$merimage,
            'qub_expiry'=>$this->input->post('txtExpiry'),
            'qub_permission'=>0,
            'qub_dated'=>time(),
            'qub_ipadd'=>$ip
        );

        $inserted_id = $this->quotemerchant_model->forminsert($data7);
        $unitprice = $this->input->post('txtUnitprice');
        $quantity = $this->input->post('txtQuantity');
        $discount = $this->input->post('txtDiscount');
        $totalprice = $quantity * $unitprice;
        $effective = $totalprice - $discount;
        $vat = $this->input->post('txtVAT');
        $gst = $this->input->post('txtGST');
        $service = $this->input->post('txtServicetax');
        $octroi = $this->input->post('txtOctroi');
        $excise = $this->input->post('txtExcise');
        $shipping = $this->input->post('txtShipping');
        $other = $this->input->post('txtOthertaxcharges');
        $dats['gstamount'] = ($effective * $gst) / 100;
        $dats['servicetaxamt'] = ($effective * $service) / 100;
        $dats['octroiamt'] = ($effective * $octroi) / 100;
        $dats['exciseamt'] = ($effective*$excise) / 100;

        $dats['vatamt'] = ($effective + $dats['exciseamt']) * $vat / 100;
        $dats['netamount'] = $effective + $dats['gstamount'] + $dats['octroiamt'] + $dats['servicetaxamt'] + $dats['exciseamt'] + $other + $dats['vatamt']+ $shipping;
        $sellingprice= $dats['netamount'];
                 $data8=array(
            'qud_qubid' => $inserted_id,
            'qud_productid' => $this->input->post('sbProduct'),
            'qud_unit' => $this->input->post('sbUnit'),
            'qud_quantity' => $this->input->post('txtQuantity'),  
            'qud_unitprice'=>$this->input->post('txtUnitprice'),  
            'qud_vat'=>$this->input->post('txtVAT'), 
            'qud_gst'=>$this->input->post('txtGST'), 
            'qud_servicetax'=>$this->input->post('txtServicetax'), 
            'qud_octroi'=>$this->input->post('txtOctroi'),
            'qud_excise'=>$this->input->post('txtExcise'),
            'qud_othertaxcharges'=>$this->input->post('txtOthertaxcharges'),
            'qud_shipping'=>$this->input->post('txtShipping'),
            'qud_discount'=>$this->input->post('txtDiscount'),
            'qud_totalprice'=>$totalprice,
            'qud_sellingprice'=>$sellingprice,
            'qud_requirementid'=>$this->input->post('txtRequirement'),
            'qud_rfqid'=>$this->input->post('txtRFQid'),
            'qud_enduser'=>$this->input->post('txtEnduser'),
            'qud_merchantid'=>$this->input->post('merchant'),
            'qud_customerid'=>$this->input->post('customer'), 
            'qud_dated'=>time(),
            'qud_ipadd'=>$ip,
        );

                $admid=  $this->session->userdata('moderId');

           $revicedata=array(
            'rev_processtype'=>'1',
            'rev_actionlevel'=>'new',
            'rev_processdataid' => $inserted_id,
            'rev_admtype' =>2,  
            'rev_admid'=>$admid,  
             'rev_dated'=>time(),
            'rev_ipadd'=>$ip,
            );
         //  echo '<pre>'; print_r($this->session->all_userdata());exit;
           $reviceinsert=$this->quotemerchant_model->insertreviceaction($revicedata); 




          $detail=$this->quotemerchant_model->forminsertdetail($data8);
         $response=array('id'=>$inserted_id,'message'=>"inserted successfully"); 
         echo json_encode($response); 
         die();

    }
```

View

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

    $('#merchantsubmit').click(function () {

 var formData = new FormData($('#myform')[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>moderator/QuoteMerchant/addmerchant",
            type: 'POST',
           data: formData,
           dataType:"Json", 
                mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
            success: function(data) {
                var last_inserted_id = data.id;
                window.location.href ="<?php  echo base_url() ?>moderator/QuoteMerchant/viewmerchant/"+last_inserted_id;
                // window.location.href ="<?php //echo base_url()             ?>moderator/RFQ/viewrfq/"+  form_data.reqid;
//      alert('added Successfully');
            }
        });

        return false;
    });



</script>
```

Model

```
public function forminsert($data7)
{
     $this->db->insert('jil_quotemjbrief',$data7);
     return $this->db->insert_id();
}
public function forminsertdetail($data8) {
     $this->db->insert('jil_quotemjdetail',$data8);
     return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Comment: you can reload you page after ajax success or reset form

Comment: how it works? can you explain?

Comment: after successfull data insert you show success message or any other thing show

Comment: i did that,after success redirect to another page.but.ajax is somewhat slow.we get time to double click on button.so more calls gone

Comment: befor send ajax show loading image

Comment: Hello , Can't you disable submit button until Ajax Returns True / False ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i disabled the button on first click .so problem solved

Answer (score 0):

**use this code**

in view

```
 <style>
  .loading {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff url("<?php echo base_url();?>images/loading.gif") no-repeat center center;
  opacity: .2;
  z-index: 20140628;
  height:1100px;
}
```

put div

```
<div class="loading"></div>
```

and ajax

```
    <script>
        function getValue(val) {
            //alert(val);
$('.loading').show();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>moderator/QuoteMerchant/createquotemerchant",
                data: {from: "ajax", reqid: val},
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#content").html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: hai friend, i did like this ,location.reload(); after success,this works. but shows like error in console .your code also also works.

Comment: now i edit my answer you simple use any loading gif image

Comment: but when we continuosly clicking on this button.multiple entries wil inserted.how avoid?

Comment: first click the shadow come in screen and  user not click after that

Comment: this loading image automaticall comes? or we have to put it in a folder?

Comment: no you can download any loading gif image and put in your image directory on you put any where in your project just put right path

Comment: Thanx for all trying to help me

Answer (score 0):

User this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#merchantsubmit').click(function () {
    var ajaxCall = true;

    if(ajaxCall) {

        ajaxCall = false;
        var formData = new FormData($('#myform')[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>moderator/QuoteMerchant/addmerchant",
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            dataType:"Json", 
                mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
            success: function(data) {
                var last_inserted_id = data.id;
                window.location.href ="<?php  echo base_url() ?>moderator/QuoteMerchant/viewmerchant/"+last_inserted_id;
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: i updated my script.please check.on each time button click,the function wil execute

Comment: Now just use this script

Comment: did u see my updation on your script?

Comment: yes i seen your update but you can use like this as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104012/discussion-between-yogesh-shakya-and-angel).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<script>
    function getValue(val) {
        var $form = $('#formId');
        $form.find('submit').attr('disabled', true); // Disable further button click
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>moderator/QuoteMerchant/createquotemerchant",
            data: {from: "ajax", reqid: val},
            success: function (data) {
                $("#content").html(data);
            },
            complete: function() {
            $form.find('submit').removeAttr('disabled'); // On complete enable the button
            }

        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to avoid multiple submission issue in jquery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isSubmitting = false;
    $('#merchantsubmit').click(function () {
        if(isSubmitting) {
            return;
        }
        isSubmitting = true;
        var formData = new FormData($('#myform')[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>moderator/QuoteMerchant/addmerchant",
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            dataType: "Json",
            mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                isSubmitting = false;
                var last_inserted_id = data.id;
                window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url() ?>moderator/QuoteMerchant/viewmerchant/" + last_inserted_id;
                // window.location.href ="<?php //echo base_url()              ?>moderator/RFQ/viewrfq/"+  form_data.reqid;
//      alert('added Successfully');
            }
        });

        return false;
    });



</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#merchantsubmit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //it's prevent jquery
    $.ajax({
        //your configuration is here

        success: function(data) {
            //make disable your buton
            $('#your-button-id').text('Save'); //change button text
            $('#your-button-id').attr('disabled', false); //set button enable
        }
    });
});
```

well you need to give prevent in jquery the purpose only one event need to be execute, as another answer is above give disabled button jquery, hope this help you